# Square of digit that produce a number arrive to 89

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Well, I have the following problem:

Number chains are created by continuously adding the square of the digits in a number to form a new number until it has been seen before.
For example,

25 → 29 → 85 → 89 → 145 → 42 → 20 → 4 → 16 → 37 → 58 → 89

32 → 13 → 10 → 1 → 1

Therefore any chain that arrives at 1 or 89 will become stuck in an endless loop. What is most amazing is that all numbers will always arrive at either 1 or 89.
How many starting numbers below n will arrive at 89?

ex1. f(500) = 423 Time.

ex2. f(1000) = 857 Time.

ex2. f(1221) = 1043 Time.

And my current solution is:

```
public static int Solving(int n) {
    int numOf89 = 0;

    int oldN = n;
    int count = 0;
    while (count <= oldN) {
        count++;
        n = is89(n);
        if (n == 89) {

            numOf89++;
        }
    }

    return numOf89;
}



public static int is89(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    int val = 0;
    while (n >= 1) {
        val = n % 10;
        result += val * val;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

How to get the starting numbers below n that will arrive at 89?

Comment: If I understand correctly - in your code you are currently *counting* the number of integers for which the square of digits is 89, and what you want is to *list* these numbers?

Comment: What is n limit?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez I want to get the starting numbers that will arrive at 89, there are examples i provide in my question, please take a look.

Comment: @MBo what do you mean?

Comment: If max value of N is reasonable, then memoization is possible, like @user unknown approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you only try one starting number and then count the number of times you reach 89 in "starting number" steps. This will be 0 if the sequence reach 1 or about 1/8 of the starting number if you reach 89 (since the loop has length 8).

I think you want something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    count89(500);
    count89(1000);
    count89(1221);
}

public static void count89(int max) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<max; i++) {
        if (endIn89(i)) count++;
    }
    System.out.println("f(" + max + ") = " + count);
}

public static boolean endIn89(int n) {
    while (true) {
        int next = 0;
        int digit = 0;
        while (n >= 1) {
            digit = n % 10;
            next += digit * digit;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        n = next;
        if (n==1) return false;
        if (n==89) return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking to see the results, you can do a couple of things;

For one, you can just print out the results that you wish to see in the if statement using

```
System.out.println(n);
```

But if you want to store them for later, you can declare a new ArrayList and add the numbers if the "if" statement was satisfied.

If this is the approach you want to take, import ArrayLists

```
import java.util.*;
```

Then make a new ArrayList in the some part of your code before you reach the method:

```
List<> eightyNines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then in the if statement, add the numbers that are satisfied:

```
eightyNines.add(n);
```

And you can print them in an enhanced for loop:

```
for(int s : eightyNines)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

These are just two of the ways you can do this. Hoped this helped!

Comment: 89 for f(500) will always 63 and that's wrong result,

Comment: @user10548941 don't you also wanna see if the result is one? after looking into the code, the result is 1, not 89. To fix this change the "while (n >= 1)" to "while (n > 1)".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to Seans approach is, to declare a tiny Array of Booleans, with name is89y, which is by default false at every position.

While checking for a number, instead of calculating each value, you may first have a look into the array. But be aware, that the highest number you test for might lead to intermediate values, exceeding the array. This can partly been avoided by choosing a much bigger array. However - check.

A similar approach would be to use an Hashmap (int→Boolean).

Since the numbers aren't calculated in order, you should perhaps solve this recursive, so that every intermediate number get's stored in the array/hashmap. The speed improvement should be enormous.

When ready, you can lookup the array for true positions.

Proof of concept in Scala*:

```
def qdz (MAX: Int): Seq [Int] = {

    val arr = new Array [Boolean](MAX*3)

    def qdsum (n: Int) : Int = {
        if (n < 10) n*n else
        (n % 10)*(n % 10) + qdsum (n/10)
    }

    def isa89 (n: Int): Boolean = {
        if (n < MAX*3 && arr(n)) true
        else {
            val sum = qdsum (n)
            // if (sum > MAX) print (s" <<$sum>> ")
            if (sum == 1)  false else
            if (sum == 89) {
                if (n < MAX*3) arr(n) = true
                if (sum < MAX*3) arr(sum) = true
                true
            }
            else {
                val tmp = isa89 (sum)
                if (tmp && n < MAX*3) arr(n) = true
                tmp
            }
        }
    }
    val res = (1 to MAX).map (i=> isa89 (i)).filter (a => a)
    println (res.length)
    val nums= (0 to MAX).filter (i => arr(i))
    nums.foreach (i => print (i + " "))
    nums
}
val hits = qdz (100)
```

Result:

```
hits: Seq[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 83, 84, 85, 87, 88, 89, 90, 92, 93, 95, 96, 98, 99)
```

*) For a Java-Dev, probably the biggest hurdles in understanding might be, that arr(n) in Scala is like arr[n] in Java and that the return statement(s) are missing. The last expression(s) are all return statements. So:

```
    def qdsum (n: Int) : Int = {
        if (n < 10) n*n else
        (n % 10)*(n % 10) + qdsum (n/10)
    }
```

looks in Java like this:

```
    int qdsum (Int n) {
        if (n < 10) return n*n;
        else return (n % 10)*(n % 10) + qdsum (n/10);
    }
```

and

```
    def isa89 (n: Int): Boolean = {
        if (n < MAX*3 && arr(n)) true // ...
```

gets

```
    boolean isa89 (int n) {
        if (n < MAX*3 && arr[n]) return true; // ...
```